# Efficient way to calculate cross-correlation of audio input from two microphones

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, signal-processing, microphone

I am trying to calculate the cross correlation between two microphone input signals in unity3d and then take an FFT of this correlation value. The thing is, it calculates the correlation correctly, but it makes the game lag a lot.
Am I doing something wrong? Should I not be doing this in update()?
I need to get real time correlation values.

```
public class MicInput : MonoBehaviour {
AudioSource aud1, aud2;
int signalLength = 3200;
public float[] _samples1 = new float[3200];
public float[] _samples2 = new float[3200];
public double[] _newSamples1 = new double[3200];
//public double[] _newSamples2 = new double[512];

public float[] cc2 = new float[9];

public double[] dft = new double[5];


// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{

    aud1 = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    aud1.clip = Microphone.Start(Microphone.devices[3], true, 10, 16000);
    aud1.loop = true;
    aud1.mute = false;

    aud2 = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    aud2.clip = Microphone.Start(Microphone.devices[4], true, 10, 16000);
    aud2.loop = true;
    aud2.mute = false;


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    aud1.clip.GetData(_samples1, 0);
    aud2.clip.GetData(_samples2, 0);
    cc2 = MyCrossCorr(_samples1, _samples2);
}

float[] MyCrossCorr(float[] arr1, float[] arr2)
{
    int lx = arr1.Length;
    int ly = arr2.Length;
    int jmin, jmax, index;
    index = 0;
    int lconv = lx + ly - 1;
    float[] z = new float[lconv];
    for (int i = 0; i < lconv; i++)
    {
        if (i >= ly)
        {
            jmin = i - ly + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            jmin = 0;
        }

        if (i < lx)
        {
            jmax = i;
        }
        else
        {
            jmax = lx -1;
        }

        for (int j = jmin; j <= jmax; j++)
        {
            index = ly - i + j - 1;
            z[i] = z[i] + (arr1[j] * arr2[index]);

        }
    }
    //Debug.Log(z);
    return z;
 }
}
```

Comment: I guess it tries to give `_samples1` and `_samples2` to your function every frame. Try adding a control mechanism like a bool. Give the input, wait for a result. After done re-do the process

Comment: Could you please explain "control mechanism" a little more? I did not fully understand your idea @EmreE

Comment: In Update, you give your parameters to your function every frame. And function runs, seems like also does a lot of process for a single frame. I am guessing this is causing the lag. Like, add a bool on top of your function in Update. `isSamplesGiven` make it false. If this is false run your function. And when function starts make this bool true so it won't run again. When function is complete make this bool false again.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you if this works. Thanks @EmreE

Comment: Also you would like take a look to http://www.sebaslab.com/svelto-taskrunner-run-serial-and-parallel-asynchronous-tasks-in-unity3d/ seems like you can improve your performance (https://twitter.com/sebify/status/782878689176485888/photo/1), but you have to try it by yourself.

Comment: Can't really escape the fact that the complexity of calculating correlation is O(N^2) and N in this case is quite large (3200).  Processing fewer samples at once will make a drastic difference.